Why lerna version assuming all packages changed?
I use GitHub Action to publish my own package, and I made some changes in @mosiure/pkgA.
However,I found that lerna version will handle all my packages, even though I never made change in those packages.
Did I type the wrong lerna version command? Anyone can help me?
Part of my yaml file:
jobs:
  publish-monorepo:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v4

      - name: Use Node.js
        uses: actions/setup-node@v4
        with:
          node-version: 20
          registry-url: https://registry.npmjs.org/

      - name: Global Install pnpm
        run: npm i -g pnpm

      - name: Install Related Package
        run: pnpm install

      - name: Release And Tagged Version
        run: lerna version --conventional-commits --preid beta --yes

      - name: Publish Packages
        run: lerna publish from-git --yes
        env:
          NODE_AUTH_TOKEN: ${{secrets.NPM_TOKEN}}


Expecting:
lerna version won`t handle the unchanged package.
Actullay:
Run lerna version --conventional-commits --yes
  
info cli using local version of lerna
lerna notice cli v8.1.8
lerna info versioning independent
lerna info ci enabled
lerna info Assuming all packages changed
lerna info getChangelogConfig Successfully resolved preset "conventional-changelog-angular"
Changes:
 - @mosiure/pkgA: 0.6.0 => 0.6.1
 - @mosiure/pkgB: 0.5.0 => 0.5.1
lerna info auto-confirmed 
lerna info execute Skipping releases
lerna info lifecycle root@undefined~version: root@undefined
> root@undefined version /home/runner/work/demo_test/demo_test
> conventional-changelog -p angular -i CHANGELOG.md -s && git add CHANGELOG.md
lerna info git Pushing tags...
lerna success version finished

